# ACF: Display values outside the main loop

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am coding a theme that uses an archive on a page with a special template. Above the results of the archive (that also means outside of the loop) I want to display the values of some custom fields. (e.g. the value of the field “intro”. I tried to create an additional loop and have the values displayed, but there are no results. Does anybody see a mistake?
Thanks!
Raphael
Here is what I tried last:

```
<div class="newsearch_intro">
        <?php global $post; 
            $args = array('numberposts'=>'1'); 
            $custom_posts = get_posts($args);
            foreach($custom_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
            the_field('intro');
            endforeach;
        ?>          
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `the_field()` / `get_field()` with the post ID as a second parameter:

```
<div class="newsearch_intro">
    <?php
        global $post;
        the_field('intro', $post->ID);
    ?>          
</div>
```

Comment: No sorry, does not work. i had lots of different combination with your suggestion of adding the ID as a second parameter, but none of them works. I had it with echo, with a comüplete new loop and so on. nothing worked. 

I can always hardcode it, but I would like the option for the admins to change the content. But ACF support also cannot explain how to do it.

Comment: Is your custom field for posts or other type of terms? Also, are you sure that the ID for the ACF is correct ('intro'), and that the field has a value set on the post you are testing? I've been working with ACF for many years now, and it's a very reliable plugin. Try adding echo 'post id is: ' . $post->ID;  just before the_field() in your code and see if you get anything.

Comment: Thank you for all ideas. I have to say "yes" everywhere. only one thing: It is neither post not page, but it is used in a template that is used for a page, but the page lists all posts of certain categories and is additionally filtered if people look for certain information. The filter is AJAX based. 

OK, whatever. I think i will hardcode it. Thanks anyway.